# Adding a Manager using Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, azure, graph

I have a C# apI that i am working on which creates and assigns the groups to a user in Azure AD using Graph.  However I cannot seem to get it to add their manager.  The code i have is as follows;

---

```
var user = new User
        {
          Manager = new DirectoryObject
          {
              Id = managerDetails
          },
        };

        try
        {
            var result =await graphServiceClient.Users[userId]
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(user);

            return true;
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
```

---

What is that I am missing here?  I have been looking online all day and whilst it mentions PATCH, I am new to working with Graph and not sure what or how this works.  Looking at [Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contact-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tab) I can see code similar to mine but I am struggling somewhat to figure out how this is achieved.  Any help would be grateful.

Comment: COuld you please provide error message?

Comment: There is no error message or exception raised, that's the curious thing. I guess I should have made this clear, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding how to assign a manager to a user, Microsoft graph provides a unique endpoint to do that directly `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/manager/$ref`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

For example

```
  await graphClient.Users["<id>"].Manager.Reference
                .Request()
                .PutAsync("5b3bba08-f1f4-4428-a92c-0d107f91aecc");


  var user = await graphClient.Users["<id>"].Manager
              .Request()
              .GetAsync();
  Console.WriteLine(user.Id);
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this out on Monday and let you know, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, can't remember how to do this so I wasn't being rude, sorry.  Let me look again.